# Two shaders on one object

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, shader

I have problem with multiply shaders on my one object.
That's my render code:

```
#include "MeshRenderer.h"

ForwardAmbient* shader1;
ForwardDirectional* shader2;

MeshRenderer::MeshRenderer(Obj& obj) :
    meshObject(obj)
{
    shader1 = new ForwardAmbient(vec3(1, 1, 1));
    shader2 = new ForwardDirectional(vec3(1, 0, 0), vec3(1, 1, 1));
}

MeshRenderer::~MeshRenderer()
{

}

void MeshRenderer::Render(RenderingCore* rc)
{
    //for (Shader* shader : meshObject.shaders)
    //{

    //}

    shader1->Bind();
    shader1->UpdateShader(rc, transform, meshObject.material);
    meshObject.material->GetTexture()->Bind(0);
    meshObject.mesh->Render();

    shader2->Bind();
    shader2->UpdateShader(rc, transform, meshObject.material);
    meshObject.material->GetTexture()->Bind(0);
    meshObject.mesh->Render();

    /*
    meshObject.shader->Bind();
    meshObject.shader->UpdateShader(rc, transform, meshObject.material);
    meshObject.material->GetTexture()->Bind(0);
    meshObject.mesh->Render();
    */
}
```

ambient light.vs:

```
#version 120
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec2 texCoord0;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = (projection * transform) * vec4(position, 1);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
}
```

ambient light.fs:

```
#version 120

varying vec2 texCoord0;

uniform vec3 ambientLight;
uniform float alpha;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, texCoord0.xy) * vec4(ambientLight,  alpha);
}
```

directional light.vs

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying vec3 normal0;
varying vec3 worldPos0;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = (projection * transform) * vec4(position, 1);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
    normal0 = (transform * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
    worldPos0 = (transform * vec4(position, 1)).xyz;
}
```

directional light.fs

```
#version 120

varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying vec3 normal0;
varying vec3 worldPos0;

uniform vec3 color;
uniform float alpha;

uniform vec3 direction;
uniform float specularIntensity;
uniform float specularPower;
uniform vec3 eyePosition;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

vec4 calcLight(vec3 color, float alpha, vec3 direction, vec3 normal)
{
    float diffuseFactor = dot(normal, -direction);

    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0,0,0,0);
    vec4 specularColor = vec4(0,0,0,0);

    if(diffuseFactor > 0)
    {
        diffuseColor = vec4(color, 1.0) * diffuseFactor;

        vec3 directionToEye = normalize(eyePosition - worldPos0);
        vec3 reflectDirection = normalize(reflect(direction, normal));

        float specularFactor = dot(directionToEye, reflectDirection);
        specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, specularPower);

        if(specularFactor > 0)
        {
            specularColor = vec4(color, 1.0) * specularIntensity * specularFactor;
        }
    }

    return diffuseColor + specularColor;
}

vec4 calcDirectionalLight(vec3 color, float alpha, vec3 direction, vec3 normal)
{
    return calcLight(color, alpha, -direction, normal);
}

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, texCoord0.xy) *     calcDirectionalLight(color, 1, direction, normalize(normal0));
}
```

Here is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI3Ms.jpg
Only ambient light is render, directional light no

Comment: What libraries are you using?  It looks like you have two separate rendering passes in your `Render` function.  It seems like you are assuming that multiple calls to `mesh->Render()` would result in some sort of aggregation of the individual shader effects but I can't imagine that that would be the case.

Comment: Do you have blending enabled?

Comment: @OpenKastle I am using OpenGL library, glew and glfw. BDL Yes, glEnable(GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: @MisterVento3 I use the same libraries and I'm not familiar with the `Bind()`, `UpdateShader()`, and `Render()` calls so I'm assuming you wrote these yourself.  It would help if we could see all of the relevant code.

Comment: @MisterVento3 Do you have `DEPTH_TEST` enabled? If so disable before and enable after the render calls again

Comment: @OpenKastle Here is code: http://speedy.sh/mxMYn/code.rar

Comment: This is really just overdraw on the same buffer. Put all your lighting calculations in a single shader / program, or use multi-pass rendering for your lighting like modern renderers do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

> ```
> shader1->Bind();
> shader1->UpdateShader(rc, transform, meshObject.material);
> meshObject.material->GetTexture()->Bind(0);
> meshObject.mesh->Render();
>
> shader2->Bind();
> shader2->UpdateShader(rc, transform, meshObject.material);
> meshObject.material->GetTexture()->Bind(0);
> meshObject.mesh->Render();
> ```

OpenGL doesn't know what "object" are. It just draws points, lines and triangles, one at a time. To sort out depth overlap the depth buffer method is used. When you use exactly the same drawing call (`meshObject.mesh->Render`) with all the same vertex setup and depth testing enabled then one of the two draw calls will win over the other.

Also, more importantly, drawing calls don't "stack". You simply can not combine shaders simply by drawing the same thing multiple times; it may sort of work for additive processes. But that's barking up the wrong tree: Instead of saving additional work, you're duplicating the amount of work to be done.

What you should do instead is merging the two shaders into single one and draw the geometry only once, with the merged shader.

Comment: Thanks, i fix that, but i have new problem, how fix that directional light: http://imgur.com/uLEtoVF, my code: http://pastebin.com/6xyzERqC

Comment: @MisterVento3: Looks not like a shader but like a geometry problem. What appears in your image is usually the cause of using shared vertices, i.e. using the same vertex for all 3 faces of the cube it borders with. A vertex is the whole tuple `[position, normal, …]` and if you change only one bit of if, you're dealing with an entirely different vertex. And the normal differs for each face of a cube, so you have different vertices.